# AWS dynamo DB service Proxy

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I followed this tutorial to implement DynamoDB endpoint proxy service via API Gateway: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

I manage to implement the `PutItem` and `Query` actions, but when I try to make a `DeleteItem` action i get the following error:

> "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema"

That's my Get Method Integration:

```
{
   "TableName": "Notes",
   "Key": {
     "myID": {
         "S": "$input.params('ID')"
     }
   }
}
```

where myID is the primary key, 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have sort key ? or what is the data type of myID? Is it String ?

Comment: Its a string, don't have a sortkey

Comment: @notionquest i have a sortkey. In that case what would be the integration template ?